# array on the left-hand side of the matching operator

Tags: regex, perl

Found weird behavior of my script, when the left-hand side is an array:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub say {
    print @_, "\n";
}


my @arr = ('I', 'am', 'Qiang');
if (@arr =~ /Qiang/) {
    say("1: Match!!!");
} else {
    say("1: No match found");
}

@arr = ('Qiang');
if (@arr =~ /Qiang/) {
    say("2: Match!!!");
} else {
    say("2: No match found");
}

if (('Qiang') =~ /Qiang/) {
    say("3: Match!!!");
} else {
    say("3: No match found");
}
qxu@xqiang-mac-0:~/test$ ./regex_array_match.pl 
1: No match found
2: No match found
3: Match!!!
```

The code in the 2nd case and the 3rd case looks equivalent to me, yet the results are different.

What Perl is supposed to do when there is an array showing up on the left-hand side of the matching operator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `=~` operator evaluates its left operand in scalar context (it wants a string).

An array in scalar context yields the number of elements it contains, which in your case is `3` and `1`, respectively.

Thus the conditions become `"3" =~ /Qiang/` and `"1" =~ /Qiang/`, both of which are false.

If you `use strict; use warnings;` (which you always should), you will see the following warning:

```
Applying pattern match (m//) to @arr will act on scalar(@arr)
```

... which `perldoc perldiag` [explains as](https://perldoc.pl/perldiag#Applying-%25s-to-%25s-will-act-on-scalar(%25s)):

> (W misc) The pattern match (`//`), substitution (`s///`), and transliteration (`tr///`) operators work on scalar values. If you apply one of them to an array or a hash, it will convert the array or hash to a scalar value (the length of an array, or the population info of a hash) and then work on that scalar value. This is probably not what you meant to do. See ["grep" in perlfunc](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#grep) and ["map" in perlfunc](https://perldoc.pl/perlfunc#map) for alternatives.

---

To check if any element of an array matches a regex pattern, you can use `grep` as follows:

```
my @arr = ('I', 'am', 'Qiang');
if ( grep { /Qiang/ } @arr ) {
    say("At least one match!!!");
} else {
    say("No match found");
}
```

`grep` will actually return the number of matching elements when evaluated in scalar context, so this is less efficient than it could be (it will always check every array element). To stop checking after the first match is found, use [`any` from List::Util](https://perldoc.pl/List::Util#any).

Comment: Thanks, but in the 3rd case, isn't it still an array? Why there is a match in that case? The array got flattened?

Comment: @QiangXu In the 3rd case there is no array. You have a simple string in (redundant) parentheses. It's like writing `$x = (2 + 2)`; the parens aren't needed, but they don't do any harm, either.

Comment: @QiangXu "array" is a type of variable, not a type of value; parentheses do not create arrays.  (though `[]` will return a reference to an anonymous array, but that's very different)

Comment: @QiangXu In `my @arr = ('I', 'am', 'Qiang');` the parens are only used to override precedence (by default `=` has higher precedence than `,`). In `@arr = ('Qiang');` the parens are redundant and you could have simply written `@arr = 'Qiang';`.

Comment: Added a solution. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @QiangXu, Parens (`(...)`) don't create lists, much less arrays. Arrays are a type of variable, and no variables appear in `('Qiang')`. Parens just affects precedence. `('Qiang')` and `'Qiang'` both evaluate to the string scalar `Qiang` regardless of context.